# Mockito returns null in SharedPreferences after updating mockito-core to version 3.0.0

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

Consider below testing class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class DatabaseManagerTest {

    private var someStringValue = "test"
    private var mockDatabaseManager: DatabaseManager? = null
    @Mock
    internal var mockSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
    @Mock
    internal var mockEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor? = null

    @Before
    fun initMocks() {
         mockDatabaseManager = createMockSharedPreference()        
    }

    private fun createMockSharedPreference(): DatabaseManager {
        `when`<String>(
            mockSharedPreferences?.getString(
               Matchers.eq(DatabaseManager.SOME_UNIQUE_KEY),
               Matchers.anyString()
            )
        ).thenReturn(someStringValue)

        `when`(mockEditor?.commit()).thenReturn(true)

        `when`<SharedPreferences.Editor>(mockSharedPreferences?.edit()).thenReturn(mockEditor)

        return DatabaseManager(mockSharedPreferences!!)
    }

    @Test
    fun sharedPreferencesHelperUpdateAndReadStoredInformation() {
        val success = mockDatabaseManager?.insert(someStringValue)

        assertThat(
            "Checking that update method returns true",
            success, `is`(true)
        )

        val savedSharedPreferenceEntry = mockDatabaseManager?.readSomeValue()

        assertThat(
           "Checking that value is stored correctly",
           someStringValue,
           `is`(equalTo(savedSharedPreferenceEntry))
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the Database class:

```
class DatabaseManager(private val preferences: SharedPreferences) {

    companion object {
        const val SOME_UNIQUE_KEY = "some_unique_key"
    }

    fun insert(response: String): Boolean {
        try {
            val editor = preferences.edit()
            editor.putString(SOME_UNIQUE_KEY, response)
            editor.apply()

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return true
    }

    fun readSomeValue(): String? {
        return try {
            val someValue = preferences.getString(SOME_UNIQUE_KEY, null)
            someValue

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
}
```

When the old Mockito library is being used (1.10.19), the test passes.

When switching mockito-core to 3.0.0, I get 2 deprecated warnings for: `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)` and `Matchers`. After solving these 2 deprecated warnings, I am expecting readSomeValue() to return "test" but readSomeValue() returns `null`.

```
//    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.0.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
```

Comment: the accepted answer works with changing the mockito-core to 3.0.0. Furthermore the suggestion was correct, I was indeed doing a useless test and now I'm testing my actual code instead of the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should change the first bit of your test as shown below:

```
@Mock
lateinit var mockSharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
@Mock
lateinit var mockEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor

@Before
fun initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    mockDatabaseManager = createMockSharedPreference()
}
```

You are not initialising your mock objects which hence the member variables are not assigned values.

Second of all, **SharedPreferences** is an android component and cannot be unit tested the way you are trying to. In your case you are trying to insert something, test the response of your **insert** function which is always **true** anyway. Then, you are trying to fetch that value. You shouldn't test the framework but your code.

If you want to do structure your tests like that, I will recommend [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/).

I will suggest structuring your tests differently though, like verifying that the right thing is called when you are expecting to. For example,

```
@Test
fun `shared preferences insert`() {
    mockDatabaseManager?.insert(someStringValue)

    Mockito.verify(mockSharedPreferences).edit()
    Mockito.verify(mockEditor).putString(
        Mockito.eq(DatabaseManager.SOME_UNIQUE_KEY),
        Mockito.eq(someStringValue)
    )
    Mockito.verify(mockEditor).apply()
}


@Test
fun `shared preferences readSomeValue`() {
    mockDatabaseManager?.readSomeValue()

    Mockito.verify(mockSharedPreferences).getString(
        Mockito.eq(DatabaseManager.SOME_UNIQUE_KEY),
        Mockito.isNull()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> After solving these 2 deprecated warnings [...]

Please also share how you resolved these warnings. Because when I change:

```
           Matchers.eq(DatabaseManager.SOME_UNIQUE_KEY),
           Matchers.anyString()
```

to

```
           eq(DatabaseManager.SOME_UNIQUE_KEY),
           any<String>()
```

and delete the line

```
    `when`(mockEditor?.commit()).thenReturn(true)
```

to remove an error about unused mocking, then the test **pass** for me with `org.mockito:mockito-core:3.0.0`.